# Ordered Tuple : Defining projection of the n-th parameter?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to define an $n$-tuple and function to get the tuple's $n$-th projection.  Does the following definition look correct?

Definition from [Wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair):
$$(a,b) = \{\{a\}, \{a, b\}\}$$

A function can now represent this:
$$p(a,b) = (a,b)$$

My definition of an ordered n-tuple.  I use $\tau$ to represent the terminating element of the tuple.

$$\tau \in (U \cap {\mathcal O}^C)$$

$$L = p(x_1, p(x_2, p(\ldots, p(x_n, \tau))))$$

N-tuple projection function where $\pi_2^{n-1}$ is the $n - 1$th function composition:

$$\alpha_1(P) = \pi_1(P)$$

$$\alpha_n(P) = 
\begin{cases}
    \tau,& \text{if } \pi_2^{n-1}(P) = \tau\\
    \pi_1(\pi_2^{n-1}(P)),              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Where $n > 1$

For reference the ordered pair projection functions are defined on [Wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair) as:

$$\pi_1(p) = \bigcup\bigcap p$$

$$\pi_2(p) = \bigcup\left\{\left. x \in \bigcup p\,\right|\,\bigcup p \neq \bigcap p \implies x \notin \bigcap p \right\}$$

Comment: Ugh; just for information, the usual way to define an $n$-tuple once you have then notion of an ordered pair is to define it as *function*: an $n$-tuple of elements of $X$ is a function $f\colon n\to X$, where $n=\{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$.

Comment: Making above equivalent to your proposal: $\alpha_n(P) = f(n)$ where $f: I \rightarrow P$, with index set $n \in I$.  I'm assuming the definition of the Kuratowski (or primitive) ordered pair is theory that is used in the definition of a function?  Also curious per your suggestion if $(p_n = (a_0, ..., a_z)(n)) \land n \in I$ is correct?  This assumes $(a_0,..., a_z) = (f : I \rightarrow X)$.

Comment: Yes; once you defined ordered pair (via either the Kuratowski definition or any definition that satisfies $(a,b)=(c,d)\iff a=c\wedge b=d$), you define a function from $A$ to $B$ as a subset $f\subseteq A\times B$ satisfying that $\forall a\in A(\exists b\in B((a,b)\in f)$ and $\forall a\in A$, $b,b’\in B$ $((a,b)\in f\wedge (a,b’)\in f)\implies b=b’$.  Not sure why you introduce $I$ into the mix (I’m using $n$); you seem to be defining an $I$-tuple, not an $n$-tuple.

Comment: Similarly, Bourbaki Sets s5.3 defines the ordered I-tuple as the product of a family of sets $(X_t)_{t \in I}$. Where $A = \cup_{\iota \in I} X_{\iota}$, $F \in \mathcal{P}(I \times A)$, $F$ is functional, all ordered tuples $Z = \{F :\forall \iota( F(\iota) \in X_{\iota}))\} = (X_t)_{t \in I} = (\prod_{\iota \in I} X_{\iota}) \subset \mathcal{P}(I \times A)$.  The coordinate of the index for tuple $F \in Z$ is $F(\iota).$

Comment: @ArturoMagidin unfortunately a little clunky to define $(a,b)$ using the Kuratowski definition so you can define functions but then having a second different definition of $(a,b)$ as a length 2 sequence. But… the clumsiness seems worth it to avoid a lot of clunkier inductive definitions like in this question.